# How to tell if Ubuntu SSD is corrupted/near death?

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

Last night when I rebooted my Ubuntu environment because it was seeming quite slow, it stuck at a warning screen with several lines of text (don't have, something about `radeon Invalid ROM contents`). I thought nothing of it and foolishly rebooted again, which gave way to this long screen:

```
[ 160.053495] rc.loal[1933]: systemctl start teamviewerd.service
[ 182.741532] sd 6:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 182.741559] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 182.741575] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[ 360.134840] INFO: task systemd:3622 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 360.134871]       Tainted: G      OE   4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu
[ 360.134898] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message
... Above three lines duplicated several times without only slightly different output
[ 504.125921] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 tuck for 22s! [systemd:1]
... More (but I am tired of transposing from picture)
```

**Setup:**

- AMD R9 390 graphics card (`radeon` in first paragraph?)
- 2 SSDs (Windows & Ubuntu)
- 1 HDD (partitioned between the two)

Some of these messages prompted me to start looking at whether my Ubuntu SSD may  be corrupted or nearing death - would that explain why operations seemed to take longer than usual? For example, my file watching (developer) seemed to struggle more than normal and opening project files took longer than I remember.

From recommendations online I installed `smartmontools` and ran the following:

```
sudo smartctl -H /dev/sda
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sda
sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
```

This was the output of said test [Pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com/JKJukwqr). Unfortunately I am not a hardware guy and have not a clue where to go from here. Does the output of the tests in any suggest drive failure?

```
kendall: ~ $ sudo smartctl -H /dev/sda
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-116-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

kendall: ~ $ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-116-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 850 PRO 256GB
Serial Number:    S251NXAGC17474T
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 84013365a
Firmware Version: EXM02B6Q
User Capacity:    256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Mar 24 02:15:59 2018 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 136) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       19005
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       269
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       59
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   069   053   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       122
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       9782050488

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

kendall: ~ $ sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sda
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-116-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in off-line mode".
Drive command "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in off-line mode" successful.
Testing has begun.
Please wait 2 minutes for test to complete.
Test will complete after Sat Mar 24 02:18:29 2018

Use smartctl -X to abort test.
kendall: ~ $ sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-116-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     19005         -

kendall: ~ $
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I am stuck (gasp) developing on Windows until this is resolved. I can no longer boot into Ubuntu but selecting Windows from the GRUB menu works just fine. I was able to safe boot into Ubuntu and backup what little files I need, so formatting is definitely a possibility if it will help (and won't mess up boot manager).

**EDIT 1:**

I inserted the Ubuntu install drive and tried to boot from disk, but the same thing happened. I must have missed the "Press any key button", as another restart while tapping `shift` booted from the CD.

The initial output after restarting (without booting from CD) is as follows:

```
radeon 000:01;00.0: Invalid ROM contents
[   5.729634] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[   5.729660] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 185.723262] sd 6:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 185.723287] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 0
[ 185.723300] Buffer I/P error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
...eventually the screen went totally black, fixed by tapping the power button
```

The listed drive boot order is as follows:

```
Boot Override
P2: ASUS DRW-24F1ST
UEFI: CT250BX100SSD1
Windows Boot Manager (P0: Samsung SSD 805 PRO 256GB)
ubuntu (P0: Samsung SSD 850 PRO 256GB)
ubuntu (P0: Samsung SSD 850 PRO 256GB)
P3: WDC WD10EZEX-00BN5A0
P1: CT250BX100SSD1
P0: Samsung SSD 850 PRO 256GB
UEFI: ASUS DRW-24F1ST c
```

- ASUS - CD/DVD Rom
- WDC - Western Digital HDD
- Samsung - Samsung SSD
- CT - Crucial BX SSD

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks @sudodus! Unplugged the graphics card and finally was able to test Ubuntu. Ran the following commands:

```
sudo parted -ls 
sudo lsblk -f 
sudo lsblk -m 
df
```

and received this output ([Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pDc38bu5)):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ parted --help
Usage: parted [OPTION]... [DEVICE [COMMAND [PARAMETERS]...]...]
Apply COMMANDs with PARAMETERS to DEVICE.  If no COMMAND(s) are given, run in
interactive mode.

OPTIONs:
  -h, --help                      displays this help message
  -l, --list                      lists partition layout on all block devices
  -m, --machine                   displays machine parseable output
  -s, --script                    never prompts for user intervention
  -v, --version                   displays the version
  -a, --align=[none|cyl|min|opt]  alignment for new partitions

COMMANDs:
  align-check TYPE N                        check partition N for TYPE(min|opt)
        alignment
  help [COMMAND]                           print general help, or help on
        COMMAND
  mklabel,mktable LABEL-TYPE               create a new disklabel (partition
        table)
  mkpart PART-TYPE [FS-TYPE] START END     make a partition
  name NUMBER NAME                         name partition NUMBER as NAME
  print [devices|free|list,all|NUMBER]     display the partition table,
        available devices, free space, all found partitions, or a particular
        partition
  quit                                     exit program
  rescue START END                         rescue a lost partition near START
        and END
  resizepart NUMBER END                    resize partition NUMBER
  rm NUMBER                                delete partition NUMBER
  select DEVICE                            choose the device to edit
  disk_set FLAG STATE                      change the FLAG on selected device
  disk_toggle [FLAG]                       toggle the state of FLAG on selected
        device
  set NUMBER FLAG STATE                    change the FLAG on partition NUMBER
  toggle [NUMBER [FLAG]]                   toggle the state of FLAG on partition
        NUMBER
  unit UNIT                                set the default unit to UNIT
  version                                  display the version number and
        copyright information of GNU Parted

Report bugs to bug-parted@gnu.org
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -ls
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  473MB  472MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      473MB   578MB  105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      578MB   595MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      595MB   256GB  255GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: ATA CT250BX100SSD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  600MB   599MB   primary   fat32           boot
 2      600MB   16.6GB  16.0GB  primary   linux-swap(v1)
 3      16.6GB  250GB   233GB   extended
 5      16.6GB  250GB   233GB   logical   ext4


Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-00B (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  524GB   524GB  ntfs         Basic data partition  msftdata
 2      524GB   1000GB  476GB  ext4


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0 has been opened read-only.
Model: ASUS DRW-24F1ST c (scsi)
Disk /dev/sr0: 1513MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      2048B   6143B   4096B                Apple
 2      1499MB  1501MB  2425kB               EFI


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL                    UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                          
├─sda1 ntfs     Recovery                 BAB4D580B4D54015                    
├─sda2 vfat                              C0D6-29DC                            
├─sda3                                                                        
└─sda4 ntfs     Windows                  C804D78D04D77D3E                    
sdb                                                                          
├─sdb1 vfat                              29B5-C284                            
├─sdb2 swap                              8c8ffb3f-e979-4d0b-806f-b24ad949946b [SWAP]
├─sdb3                                                                        
└─sdb5 ext4                              8ea34311-c1e3-4e80-9f4c-368abc9e9ed3
sdc                                                                          
├─sdc1 ntfs     Windows Hard Drive       A2B49BFFB49BD45F                    
└─sdc2 ext4                              18e983be-738c-43d1-a944-f2165fa2d00e
sr0    iso9660  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS amd64 2016-07-19-21-27-51-00               /cdrom
loop0  squashfs                                                               /rofs
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -m
NAME     SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sda    238.5G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda1   450M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda2   100M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda3    16M root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda4 237.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
sdb    232.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdb1   571M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdb2  14.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdb3     1K root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdb5 217.4G root  disk  brw-rw----
sdc    931.5G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdc1 488.3G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdc2 443.2G root  disk  brw-rw----
sr0      1.4G root  cdrom brw-rw----
loop0    1.4G root  disk  brw-rw----
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8132648       0   8132648   0% /dev
tmpfs            1629456    9800   1619656   1% /run
/dev/sr0         1477840 1477840         0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0       1425792 1425792         0 100% /rofs
/cow             8147276   47896   8099380   1% /
tmpfs            8147276     340   8146936   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       8      5112   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            8147276       0   8147276   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            8147276     132   8147144   1% /tmp
tmpfs            1629456      56   1629400   1% /run/user/999
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

**EDIT 3:**

I ran the `boot-repair` utility and put the output at the following link (very long): [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mRjYNHd6Gf/)

**EDIT 4:**

Taking out the GPU and booting in the Ubuntu SSD worked properly; even more weirdly is that adding the GPU back (after cleaning PC thoroughly) is that I could still boot into Ubuntu.

Ran the `smartctl` tools on `/dev/sdb` (Ubuntu SSD) and received this output ([Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hae0trmd)):

```
kendall: ~ $ sudo smartctl -H /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-116-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

kendall: ~ $ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-116-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SiliconMotion based SSDs
Device Model:     CT250BX100SSD1
Serial Number:    1510F00421A8
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 1f00421a8
Firmware Version: MU01
User Capacity:    250,059,350,016 bytes [250 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Mar 24 15:21:03 2018 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
          was never started.
          Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
          without error or no self-test has ever 
          been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x71) SMART execute Offline immediate.
          No Auto Offline data collection support.
          Suspend Offline collection upon new
          command.
          No Offline surface scan supported.
          Self-test supported.
          Conveyance Self-test supported.
          Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0002) Does not save SMART data before
          entering power-saving mode.
          Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
          General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
          SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
          SCT Feature Control supported.
          SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       750
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       369
160 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
161 Valid_Spare_Block_Cnt   0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       68
163 Initial_Bad_Block_Count 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       23
164 Total_Erase_Count       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       15976
165 Max_Erase_Count         0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       54
166 Min_Erase_Count         0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
167 Average_Erase_Count     0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       13
168 Max_Erase_Count_of_Spec 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2000
169 Remaining_Lifetime_Perc 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       100
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0000   100   100   050    Old_age   Offline      -       0
178 Runtime_Invalid_Blk_Cnt 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       79
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       25
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       203057
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0000   100   100   016    Old_age   Offline      -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0000   100   100   050    Old_age   Offline      -       2
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       100
241 Host_Writes_32MiB       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       72772
242 Host_Reads_32MiB        0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       80981
245 Flash_Writes_32MiB      0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       127808

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

kendall: ~ $ sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-116-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in off-line mode".
Drive command "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in off-line mode" successful.
Testing has begun.
Please wait 2 minutes for test to complete.
Test will complete after Sat Mar 24 15:23:52 2018

Use smartctl -X to abort test.
kendall: ~ $ sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-116-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       238         -

kendall: ~ $
```

Comment: There are Input/Output errors related to /dev/sdd, while you've tested /dev/sda. To check the device, you need to look at SMART data, and to check the filesystem on the device, run `sudo fsck -y -V /dev/sdd`. Both can be done from a live USB.

Comment: 'SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED' indicates that there is no serious damage, but as indicated by @mikewhatever, maybe you tested the wrong drive. What drive was `/dev/sdd` ?  I think the problem is somewhere else. Maybe the file system is corrupted. Maybe the RAM is damaged. But 'radeon Invalid ROM contents' indicates a hardware problem with the Radeon graphics card.

Comment: @mikewhatever You are right, thank you, I didn't notice this. I'm afraid I will have to wait to test this until next week due to a large project due on the weekend. Thanks for the direction though!

Comment: @sudodus I'm not sure what drive `/dev/sdd` is actually, it may be the HDD? I doubt that the RAM is damaged because Windows appears to be working perfectly fine. To me that also means that if the HDD is corrupted, only the portion partitioned to Ubuntu is so.

Comment: This can be the case, particularly if Ubuntu was shutdown in a hard way with the power button. That can damage the file system (but the hardware is probably still good). The first drive `/dev/sda` is usually an internal drive, and `/dev/sdd` is the fourth drive detected, maybe an external drive. On which drive is Ubuntu installed?

Comment: You can boot from a live drive (an Ubuntu install drive or some linux rescue drive) and run some commands to help identify the drives and their content. One good alternative is [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Run the diagnostic tool, upload the result and link to it in order to help us help you. (Do not run the repair tool yet.)

Comment: @sudodus See the first edit in the question, I don't think I succeeded in booting from the disk :( . Looking at the posted boot order, does anything look strange?

**EDIT**: I must have missed the "Press any key to boot from disk" menu, trying again while tapping shift displayed the ubuntu disc menu"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75033/discussion-between-sudodus-and-kendall-roth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After **testing** and discussion in a [chat forum](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75033/discussion-between-sudodus-and-kendall-roth) Ubuntu works in the computer again.

- The Ubuntu SSD passed the `smartmontools` test
- The Radeon graphics card was unplugged, cleaned and re-plugged. Maybe there was a bad electric connection, and unplugging and re-plugging fixed that issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help with this issue. I was able to finally use it again last night and haven't seen anything major yet.

Comment: @KendallRoth, You are welcome. Let us hope that it will continue to work for a long time :-)